# Custom VIew Onclick Style change

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I have  custom animated play/pause button which is getting highlighted when I press it. How can I remove the highlighted gray color around the button.
Setting background to transparent isn't working.

```
public class PlayPauseMiniView extends FrameLayout {
private static final long PLAY_PAUSE_ANIMATION_DURATION = 200;

private final PlayPauseDrawable mDrawable;
private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();

private AnimatorSet mAnimatorSet;
private int mWidth;
private int mHeight;

public PlayPauseMiniView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mDrawable = new PlayPauseDrawable(context);
    mDrawable.setCallback(this);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    final int size = Math.min(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
    setMeasuredDimension(120, 120);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(final int w, final int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, w, h);
    mWidth = w;
    mHeight = h;

}


@Override
protected boolean verifyDrawable(Drawable who) {
    return who == mDrawable || super.verifyDrawable(who);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    mDrawable.draw(canvas);
}

public void toggle() {
    if (mAnimatorSet != null) {
        mAnimatorSet.cancel();
    }

    mAnimatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
    final Animator pausePlayAnim = mDrawable.getPausePlayAnimator();
    mAnimatorSet.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    mAnimatorSet.setDuration(PLAY_PAUSE_ANIMATION_DURATION);
    mAnimatorSet.playTogether(pausePlayAnim);
    mAnimatorSet.start();
}
```

}

```
public class PlayPauseDrawable extends Drawable {

private static final Property<PlayPauseDrawable, Float> PROGRESS =
        new Property<PlayPauseDrawable, Float>(Float.class, "progress") {
            @Override
            public Float get(PlayPauseDrawable d) {
                return d.getProgress();
            }

            @Override
            public void set(PlayPauseDrawable d, Float value) {
                d.setProgress(value);
            }
        };

private final Path mLeftPauseBar = new Path();
private final Path mRightPauseBar = new Path();
private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();
private final RectF mBounds = new RectF(0,0,10,10);
private final float mPauseBarWidth;
private final float mPauseBarHeight;
private final float mPauseBarDistance;

private float mWidth;
private float mHeight;

private float mProgress;
private boolean mIsPlay;

public PlayPauseDrawable(Context context) {
    final Resources res = context.getResources();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    mPauseBarWidth = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.pause_bar_width);
    mPauseBarHeight = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.pause_bar_height);
    mPauseBarDistance = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.pause_bar_distance);
}

@Override
protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
    super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
    mBounds.set(bounds);
    mWidth = mBounds.width();
    mHeight = mBounds.height();
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    mLeftPauseBar.rewind();
    mRightPauseBar.rewind();

    // The current distance between the two pause bars.
    final float barDist = lerp(mPauseBarDistance, 0, mProgress);
    // The current width of each pause bar.
    final float barWidth = lerp(mPauseBarWidth, mPauseBarHeight / 2f, mProgress);
    // The current position of the left pause bar's top left coordinate.
    final float firstBarTopLeft = lerp(0, barWidth, mProgress);
    // The current position of the right pause bar's top right coordinate.
    final float secondBarTopRight = lerp(2 * barWidth + barDist, barWidth + barDist, mProgress);

    // Draw the left pause bar. The left pause bar transforms into the
    // top half of the play button triangle by animating the position of the
    // rectangle's top left coordinate and expanding its bottom width.
    mLeftPauseBar.moveTo(0, 0);
    mLeftPauseBar.lineTo(firstBarTopLeft, -mPauseBarHeight);
    mLeftPauseBar.lineTo(barWidth, -mPauseBarHeight);
    mLeftPauseBar.lineTo(barWidth, 0);
    mLeftPauseBar.close();

    // Draw the right pause bar. The right pause bar transforms into the
    // bottom half of the play button triangle by animating the position of the
    // rectangle's top right coordinate and expanding its bottom width.
    mRightPauseBar.moveTo(barWidth + barDist, 0);
    mRightPauseBar.lineTo(barWidth + barDist, -mPauseBarHeight);
    mRightPauseBar.lineTo(secondBarTopRight, -mPauseBarHeight);
    mRightPauseBar.lineTo(2 * barWidth + barDist, 0);
    mRightPauseBar.close();

    canvas.save();

    // Translate the play button a tiny bit to the right so it looks more centered.
    canvas.translate(lerp(0, mPauseBarHeight / 8f, mProgress), 0);

    // (1) Pause --> Play: rotate 0 to 90 degrees clockwise.
    // (2) Play --> Pause: rotate 90 to 180 degrees clockwise.
    final float rotationProgress = mIsPlay ? 1 - mProgress : mProgress;
    final float startingRotation = mIsPlay ? 90 : 0;
    canvas.rotate(lerp(startingRotation, startingRotation + 90, rotationProgress), mWidth / 2f, mHeight / 2f);

    // Position the pause/play button in the center of the drawable's bounds.
    canvas.translate(mWidth / 2f - ((2 * barWidth + barDist) / 2f), mHeight / 2f + (mPauseBarHeight / 2f));

    // Draw the two bars that form the animated pause/play button.
    canvas.drawPath(mLeftPauseBar, mPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mRightPauseBar, mPaint);

    canvas.restore();
}

public Animator getPausePlayAnimator() {
    final Animator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, PROGRESS, mIsPlay ? 1 : 0, mIsPlay ? 0 : 1);
    anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            mIsPlay = !mIsPlay;
        }
    });
    return anim;
}

public boolean isPlay() {
    return mIsPlay;
}

private void setProgress(float progress) {
    mProgress = progress;
    invalidateSelf();
}

private float getProgress() {
    return mProgress;
}

@Override
public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
    invalidateSelf();
}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
    mPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
    invalidateSelf();
}

@Override
public int getOpacity() {
    return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
}

/**
 * Linear interpolate between a and b with parameter t.
 */
private static float lerp(float a, float b, float t) {
    return a + (b - a) * t;
}
```

}

Comment: I would also like to know as to why this question is flagged down so that I can improve the quality of questions asked. Thank You.

Comment: amit frm were you are using the image ,may be you have not the background transparent for the Imagebutton try icon frm here https://github.com/google/material-design-icons

Comment: I am not using any image. The button is drawn by using canvas

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ImageView` instead of `ImageButton`

Comment: it is a custom view. The button is drawn using canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried android:background="@null" ?